# Not able to log in to site and scrape data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the site data, but facing issue while logging in to the site. when I log in to the site with username and password it does not do so.
I think there is an issue with the token, every time I try to login to the system a token is generated(check in the console headers)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.session()
url = "http://indiatechnoborate.tymra.com"

with requests.Session() as s:
    first = s.get(url)
    start_soup = BeautifulSoup(first.content, 'lxml')
    print(start_soup)
    retVal=start_soup.find("input",{"name":"return"}).get('value')
    print(retVal)
    formdata=start_soup.find("form",{"id":"form-login"})
    dynval=formdata.find_all('input',{"type":"hidden"})[1].get('name')
    print(dynval)
    dictdata={"username":"username", "password":"password","return":retVal,dynval:"1"
    }
    print(dictdata) 
    pr = {"task":"user.login"}
    print(pr)
    sec = s.post("http://indiatechnoborate.tymra.com/component/users/",data=dictdata,params=pr)
    print("------------------------------------------")
print(sec.status_code,sec.url)
print(sec.text)
```

I want to log in to the site and want to get the data after login is done

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line:

```
dictdata={"username":"username", "password":"password","return":retVal,dynval:"1"}
```

with this one:

```
dictdata={"username":"username", "password":"password","return":retVal + "==",dynval:"1"}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to use authentication methods instead of passing in payload

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
USERNAME = "<USERNAME>"
PASSWORD = "<PASSWORD>"
BASIC_AUTH = HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
LOGIN_URL = "http://indiatechnoborate.tymra.com"
response = requests.get(LOGIN_URL,headers={},auth=BASIC_AUTH)
```